# WordPress: Query all posts within a term, plus specific posts by ID that may be in a different term

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to use get_posts to return all posts within a specific term, plus some specific posts that may exist in another term. Ideally, I want to do this within one query. The issue is tax_query overrides any posts that aren't in that term. This is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'books',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'include'       => array(3181, 3180), //these are specific books that can be in any term
    'tax_query'       => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(152) //plus I need to get all books within this term
        );
    );
);

$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
var_dump($my_posts);
```

This only returns the posts within the fiction genre. This does not return the books with ID's 3181 and 3180.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`post__in` is used to retrieve specific posts ids.

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `post__in` | (array) – use post ids. Specify posts to retrieve. ATTENTION If you use sticky posts, they will be included (prepended!) in the posts you retrieve whether you want it or not. To suppress this behaviour use `ignore_sticky_posts`. |

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

```
<?php

// First query, taxonomy query
$args_1 = get_posts( array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_count' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'module',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => '010-01-01',
    )
  ),
) );

// Second query, specific posts query
$args_2 = get_posts( array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_count' => -1,
  'post_in' => array( 89, 9156, 6874, 615, ),
) );

// Merge queries
$posts = array_merge( $args_1, $args_2 );

// Push posts IDs to new array
$identifiers = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

  array_push( $identifiers, $post->ID );

};

// New query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'question',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_count' => -1,
  'post_in' => array_unique( $identifiers ),
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
  
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    
    $query->the_post();

    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );

  endwhile; 

endif;
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be a 2-query solution, though. I guess it's just not possible to get this into one? This is going to be for a fairly high-traffic page, so I'm trying to keep the code as minimal as possible. Might end up using a custom query if there isn't a 1-query solution.

Comment: No. Having multiple queries do not impact page speed. It's a myth that has no basis what so ever. What impact speed is BAD query handling. eg: using '-1' for 'post_count', as you're requesting all posts, the load can be enormous. instead use paginations, or infinite scroll. Dont use arguments that are deprecated, eg: `numberposts`. And reset your custom queries at the end.